# Is there a way to visualise the changes to an ADF pipeline when reviewing a PR?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, pull-request

I am currently reviewing between 5-15 pull requests a week on a project being developed using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) (ADF) and [Databricks](https://www.databricks.com).

Most pull requests contain changes to our ADF pipelines, which [gets stored in source code as nested JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json).

What I've found is that, as a reviewer, being able to *visually* see the changes being made to an ADF pipeline in the pull request make a huge difference in the speed and accuracy at which I can perform my review. Obviously, I can check out the branch and go view the pipelines for that branch directly on ADF, but that does not give me a *differential view*.

My question is this: Is there a way to parse two ADF pipeline json objects (source and destination branch versions of the same file) and generate a visual representation of each object? Ideally highlighting the differences, but just showing them would be a good first stab.

**Bonus points** if we can fit this into a Azure DevOps release pipeline and generate it automatically as part of the CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: You are asking for a feature from Microsoft, not a solution that is currently present.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Azure DevOps then you should have exactly what you are wanting available in every Pull Request. For any Pull Request you can click on the Files tab and it will show a side by side comparison of every file. It color codes it and includes additions, updates, and removals. It is very helpful for review. Please refer to this screenshot for details and illustration:

[image: Azure DevOps Pull Request File View]

[image: DevOps PR GIF example]

Comment: Yes, this is the built-in diff functionality that I'm very aware of. My question is about converting this to a _visual diff_.

Comment: Apologies, I mean technically the way you worded your question it sounds like I answered it 100%, "Is there a way to PARSE TWO ADF JSON OBJECTS (source and destination branch versions of the same file) and generate a VISUAL REPRESENTATION of each object? Ideally HIGHLIGHTING THE DIFFERENCES, but just showing them would be a good first stab.